# Existence of a countable basis in the definition of a manifold and uncountable bases.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

In the definition of a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ in *An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry* by William M. Boothby (page 6), the third criterion is

> $M$ has a countable basis of open sets.

How is $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology a manifold, when its usual basis (the set of open intervals) is not countable?

Sorry I am new to differential geometry, my question may seem silly, but I don't understand of that definition.

Comment: I've reword the second sentence of the question for clarity, but please check that I've preserved your intended meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Although $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, it has a countable basis of open sets meaning that there exists a countable set of open sets $\left(\mathcal{O}_i\right)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ that generate the topology.

More precisely any open set $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a union of a subset of the base. It is enough to prove the fact for open intervals and this in turn is a consequence of the density of the rationals in the reals.

Answer (score 1):

The criterion is that $M$ has some basis which is countable, not that all bases of $M$ are countable (the latter condition is false for nonempty manifolds of dimension $> 0$).

**Hint** The rational numbers, $\Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$ w.r.t. the usual topology.